# Create List item Sharepoint 2010 REST with Choice column

Tags: 2010, rest, spservices

I am trying to create one new list item in Sharepoint 2010 using REST.

Coding

```
var itemProperties = {
'Title': ;Raja;, //Single line String
'Expiry_x0020‌​_Date': "02/02/2016", //Date
'Permission_x0020‌​_Type': 'Add' //Choice Column
};

createListItemREST('http://xyz:5000/sites/n/', 'L2', itemProperties, function(task){ 
console.log('Task' + task.TaskName + ' has been created');}, function(error){ console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); });

function createListItemREST(webUrl,listName, itemProperties, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

i am getting following error.

> 400 Bad request
>
> {"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Error processing request
>   stream. The property name 'Expiry_x0020‌​_Date' specified for type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.L2Item' is not valid."}}

**Note:**
When trying with only Title column this coding is working.

**Column Details**

Title - Single Line Text

Business Justification for Access - Choice Column

Expiry Date - Date and Time

Permission Type - Choice Column

```
 <ViewFields xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments" />
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" />
      <FieldRef Name="Business_x0020_Justification_x00" />
      <FieldRef Name="Expiry_x0020_Date" />
      <FieldRef Name="Permission_x0020_Type" />
 </ViewFields>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got solution to my question.

After Updating the **itemProperties** i had get resolved of my issue.

Updated Code.

```
var itemProperties = {
'Title': userAccName,
'BusinessJustificationForAccessValue': busJust,
'ExpiryDate': expDate,
'PermissionTypeValue': 'Add'
};
```

When i browse my list with REST URL(http://xyz:5000/sites/n/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/L2) in browser i got above column names change in REST result see below.

```
 <content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:ContentTypeID>0x010093251D5BCE625C418182AA4A1133397B</d:ContentTypeID>
    <d:Title>Test</d:Title>
    <d:BusinessJustificationForAccessValue>Audit</d:BusinessJustificationForAccessValue>
    <d:ExpiryDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-02-10T00:00:00</d:ExpiryDate>
    <d:PermissionTypeValue>Add</d:PermissionTypeValue>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">30</d:Id>
    <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
    <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-02-02T06:26:37</d:Modified>
    <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-02-02T06:26:37</d:Created>
    <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:CreatedById>
    <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:ModifiedById>
    <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
    <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
    <d:Path>/sites/raja/Lists/L2</d:Path>
  </m:properties>
</content>
```